# Getting XML Attribute with XMLReader and PHP

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

I don't understand why I can't reference the XML Attribute 'headendId'.  I've referenced several posts on this and my syntax seems to be fine?  Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open('file.xml');

while($reader->read())
{
    if($reader->nodeType == XMLREADER::ELEMENT && $reader->localName == 'headend')
{   
//$reader->read();
$headend = (string)$reader->getAttribute('headendId');
echo $headend;
}
}
```

(xml is)

```
<lineup>
 <headend headendId="something">
  <name>some name</name>
  <ids>ids</ids>
  <codes>codes</codes>
 </headend>
</lineup>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't advance to the next *node* with `->read()` once you found it (an attribute is not a node):

```
while ($reader->read())
{
        if ($reader->nodeType === XMLREADER::ELEMENT 
            && $reader->localName === 'headend')
        {
                echo $reader->getAttribute('headendId');
        }
}
```

Comment: I tried that earlier, and again (see edit) and still do not get a result?

Comment: I get a result with this very code without a problem. Which means... you probably don't load the correct XML file?

Comment: Okay apparently it IS working... but I can only see it if I view source on my page when the script finishes?

Comment: Essentially what I want to do is store this attribute as a string, and then insert that string into a database.  I now see that I am finding the attribute, but when I try to insert it to the database, it is blank table, much like my screen is showing nothing, without view-source.

Comment: That's another issue, blank screens usually mean fatal errors, enable `error_reporting` to report _all_ errors, and set `display_errors` ON, see also the question 'I have a typical "does not work" problem. What should I do before asking a question?' in the [php info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info)

Comment: Okay nevermind.  It works now?  I don't know what the deal was there.  Maybe I missed an upload or something.  Taking out the read-> seemed to have worked.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It works similar as outlined [last time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15351723/367456):

```
require('xmlreader-iterators.php'); // https://gist.github.com/hakre/5147685

$elements = new XMLElementIterator($reader, 'headend');
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    echo $element->getAttribute('headendId'), "\n";
}
```

The `XMLElementIterator` allows to iterate over specific elements only, here you want the `headend` elements.

Then on each element you can call the `getAttribute()` method to fetch the string value of the headend headendId attribute.